# (Visual C#) How to read TXT file to a Combo box

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

Say I have a file on my desktop, `test.txt`. I would like to have each line set to a different item on a combo box. I already have a `string[] lines` with all the lines from the text file, I just need to figure out how to put them into the combo box.

For those who might understand it better:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    Combobox.[i] = lines[i];
}
```

Edit: Yes, this is a duplicate, but this thread contains a clearer question/answer

Comment: comboBox1.Items.Add(lines[i]);

Comment: @KenWhite In Visual Studio when you create a new project, the templates for C# are listed under `Visual C#`. What is your point? And how does it help with the answer?

Comment: @KenWhite Check yourself before you embarrass yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it simply by using the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    Combobox.Items.Add(lines[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give you desired output. Lets say your string[] is lines

```
foreach (string data in lines)
{
comboBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text=data });
}
```